# Drop Duolicates in a Panda DataFrame for timestampe in a certain threshold

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates, mask

I have a Dataframe as follows and would like to remove duplicates with respect to three columns: `user`, `url` and `timestamp` (only if it is less than or equal `<= 10 sec` of last occurrence). Here I elaborate rows with `#` comment:

```
    timestamp                   user    url
0   2018-02-07 00:00:00+02:00   ip0     google.com # 1st occurrence
1   2018-02-07 00:00:02+02:00   ip1     xe.com # 1st occurrence
2   2018-02-07 00:00:10+02:00   ip7     facebook.com
3   2018-02-07 00:00:11+02:00   ip1     xe.com # duplicate <= 10 sec : drop
4   2018-02-07 00:00:13+02:00   ip1     xe.com # not a duplicate, comparing with 1st occurrence : leave it
5   2018-02-07 00:00:15+02:00   ip2     example.com
6   2018-02-07 00:00:20+02:00   ip3     ebay.com
7   2018-02-07 00:00:55+02:00   ip1     xe.com # not a duplicate: leave it
8   2018-02-07 00:00:59+02:00   ip5     amazon.com
9   2018-02-07 00:01:02+02:00   ip1     xe.com # duplicate <= 10 sec : drop
10  2018-02-07 00:01:28+02:00   ip0     google.com # not a duplicate: leave it
```

I tried `df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['user', 'url'], keep='first')` which removes all possible duplicate regardless of `timestamp`.

My expected results should look something like this:

```
    timestamp                   user    url
0   2018-02-07 00:00:00+02:00   ip0     google.com
1   2018-02-07 00:00:02+02:00   ip1     xe.com
2   2018-02-07 00:00:10+02:00   ip7     facebook.com
4   2018-02-07 00:00:13+02:00   ip1     xe.com
5   2018-02-07 00:00:15+02:00   ip2     example.com
6   2018-02-07 00:00:20+02:00   ip3     ebay.com
7   2018-02-07 00:00:55+02:00   ip1     xe.com
8   2018-02-07 00:00:59+02:00   ip5     amazon.com
10  2018-02-07 00:01:28+02:00   ip0     google.com
```

What is most compact and easiest way to create some sort of mask (if that is a practical idea) to exclude rows which fall within certain threshold, e.g., 10 seconds, of the fist occurrence?

Cheers,

Comment: If you have a row that is a duplicate within 10 sec of a row being already a duplicate that you will drop, would you drop it as well? like with your data, if you have this extra row `2018-02-07 00:00:13+02:00   ip1     xe.com` that is a duplicate of your row number 3 within 10 sec, but because you will drop the row index 3, then it becomes far enough of your row number 1?

Comment: That is actually a very good observation, thanks I will update my question with your proposed row! but to answer your question, I would say the first occurrence which was identified is my main intention then look for possible duplicates in `timestamp`! therefore, I would examine your proposed row with still the fist occurrence of `2018-02-07 00:00:02+02:00   ip1     xe.com # first occurrence`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that works for your original question, but doesn't work for the new logic of "overlapping" time-windows where event1 and event2 occur within 10 seconds, and so do event2 and event3. This code is only keeping event1 in this scenario, but I see you want event1 and event3 in the update. I don't know how to get the new "overlapping" behavior without a slow loop

Solution below uses `groupby` and `shift` to identify the previous event by each user/url group, and then filters by timedelta. I think this solution is fast and scales well

```
import pandas as pd
import io #just for reading in the example table
import datetime

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""
    day timestamp                   user    url
0   2018-02-07 00:00:00+02:00   ip0     google.com
1   2018-02-07 00:00:02+02:00   ip1     xe.com
2   2018-02-07 00:00:10+02:00   ip7     facebook.com
3   2018-02-07 00:00:11+02:00   ip1     xe.com
4   2018-02-07 00:00:13+02:00   ip1     xe.com
5   2018-02-07 00:00:15+02:00   ip2     example.com
6   2018-02-07 00:00:20+02:00   ip3     ebay.com
7   2018-02-07 00:00:55+02:00   ip1     xe.com
8   2018-02-07 00:00:59+02:00   ip5     amazon.com
9   2018-02-07 00:01:02+02:00   ip1     xe.com
10  2018-02-07 00:01:28+02:00   ip0     google.com
"""),delim_whitespace=True)

df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['day']+' '+df['timestamp']) #get timestamp column as datetime

#Make a new column of the previous times, by user/url, for each row 
df['prev_time'] = df.groupby(['url','user'])['timestamp'].shift()

#keep rows which either don't have a previous time (null), or are more than 10 seconds timedelta from prev
threshold = datetime.timedelta(0,10) #0 days, 10 seconds
filt_df = df[df['prev_time'].isnull() | df['timestamp'].sub(df['prev_time']).gt(threshold)]

print(filt_df)
```

Here's the output `filt_df` table

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I would make an additional column from the timestamp column - seconds, and then do something like the following:

```
df = pd.concat([df[df['seconds']<=10].drop_duplicates(subset=['timestamp', 'user', 'url'], keep='first'), df[df['seconds']>10]])
```

But I think there is a more compact and convenient way.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it does not return the expected results in the question